# Knowing binomial expansion of $(1+kx)^n$ shortcut for $(a+kx)^n$

Tags: binomial-theorem

If I've calculated the binomial expansion of $(1+kx)^n$ (where $k$ and $n$ are known) up to some term, is there then a shortcut for calculating $(a+kx)^n$?

---

Example: Given that the binomial expansion of $(1+6x)^{\frac23}$ up to and including the term in $x^2$ is $1+4x-4x^2$, what is the binomial expansion of $(8+6x)^{\frac23}$ (up to and including the term in $x^2$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [gammatester's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727305/knowing-binomial-expansion-of-1kxn-shortcut-for-akxn/#1727308) and the help I received from Henning Makholm in its comment section, I realised this:

---

Let $\ f(x)=(1+kx)^n$, then, because,

$$
(a+kx)^n=\left(a\left(1+\frac{kx}a\right)\right)^n=a^n\left(1+k\frac{x}{a}\right)^n
$$ you can calculate

$$
(a+kx)^n=a^nf\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)
$$

So basically, each term ($x^m$) in the series has to be divided by $a$ to the same power ($a^m$) and then the whole series must be multiplied by $a$, thus your example becomes:

> \begin{align*}(8+6x)^\frac23\approx 8^\frac23+\frac{8^\frac23\cdot 4x}8-\frac{8^\frac23\cdot 4x^2}{8^2}\approx 4+2x-\frac{x^2}4\end{align*}

Comment: Since the RHS is an approximation of the LHS you should write $+\cdots$ at the and of the RHS similar to the answer of @YvesDaoust.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer The example asked for only up to and including term in $x^2$, but I know what you mean.

Comment: Allright. Since we don't need to add any more terms, we could use $\approx$ instead of $=$ to provide  a valid statement. Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

> *Hint*: Let's assume you already know $$f(x)=(1+kx)^n$$
>
> Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> (a+kx)^n=a^n\left(1+k\frac{x}{a}\right)^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>    you can calculate
>
> \begin{align*}
> (a+kx)^n=a^nf\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:* Some details due to OPs comment

- In (1) we use
  \begin{align*}
  (a+kx)^n&=\left(\frac{a}{a}\left(a+kx\right)\right)^n\\
  &=\left(a\cdot\frac{a+kx}{a}\right)^n\\
  &=\left(a\left(1+\frac{kx}{a}\right)\right)^n\\
  &=a^n\left(1+k\frac{x}{a}\right)^n\tag{3}\\
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we use
  \begin{align*}
  a^nf\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=a^n\left(1+k\frac{x}{a}\right)^n=(a+kx)^n
  \end{align*}
  according to (3)

Comment: This is an answer I already arrived at in the comments of another answer. Perhaps you could provide the full explanation? And please fix the formatting xP

Comment: @theonlygusti: I've added some details which might help to clarify questions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$(a+kx)^n=\left(a(1+kx/a)\right)^n = a^n(1+kx/a)^n$$
Of course this assumes that all powers exist, which would be the case for natural $n,$ but e.g. not for $n=2/3, a=-2.$

Comment: But then (I may be wrong, I am not yet very familiar with binomial expansions) don't I still have to go through the arduous process of (re-)calculating $(1+\frac{k}{a}x)^n$?

Comment: @theonlygusti: Think of it as calculating $(1+k\frac xa)^n$ instead -- that is, just divide every term by the same power of $a$ as it already has of $x$.

Comment: I see, you want the complete binomial expansion.  Then yes, my hint does not offer a practical solution. I may delete the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, so then (as per my example): $(8+6x)^{\frac23}$ becomes $1+\frac{4x}8-\frac{4x^2}{8^2}$?

Comment: @theonlygusti: Yes, except that you then need to multiply the entire polynomial with $a^n$ too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Great! That actually provides a perfect answer, perhaps you could provide an answer explaining this process?

Comment: Or let gammatester know and give them the opportunity to update their answer :)

Comment: @theonlygusti: gammatester is automatically notified of every comment on his answer.

Comment: I know, and it seems that @markus scheuer did it already.

Answer (score 2):

As an equivalent alternative to gammatester's answer, you can also just multiply an appropriate power of $a$ onto every term, such that the sum of the powers of $x$ and $a$ is $n$. This is because the general term in the binomial expansion of $(1+kx)^n$ is
$$ c1^{n-j}(kx)^j $$
for some $c$, and in the expansion of $(a+kx)^n$ you get terms
$$ ca^{n-j}(kx)^j $$
but otherwise with the same constants.

Answer (score 1):

It was enough to begin with

$$(1+x)^q=1+qx+\frac{(q)_{2}}2x^2+\frac{(q)_3}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$

Then you get

$$(a+kx)^q=a^q\left(1+\frac{kx}a\right)^q$$

by substituting $\dfrac{kx}a$ for $x$ and multiplying the whole by $a^q$, giving after simplification of the powers of $a$:

$$(a+kx)^q=a^q+qa^{q-1}kx+\frac{(q)_{2}}2a^{q-2}k^2x^2+\frac{(q)_{3}}{3!}a^{q-3}k^3x^3+\cdots$$

---

Note: $(q)_k$ is the "falling factorial" $q(q-1)\cdots(q-k+1)$.